# Android Studio not displaying Activity.Main design view

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, themes

I am using Android Studio (3.1.4 for Windows 64-bit), and have an issue whenever I start a new project.

When I initially look at activity_main.xml, the design view and blueprint view are blank. I cannot interact with them. However, I can in the component tree that views are present.

To fix this problem, I go to styles.xml and change the line style 
    name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
to style
    name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
I would like to figure out how to get the design and blueprint view to work initially whenever I make a new project. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, and I changed the resource like this. You may try like this.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base" />
    <style name="Base.Theme" />
</resources>
```

Comment: I used that fix too. I was just wondering if there was a permanent fix for all future android projects to start out like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify `styles.xml.ftl`, in Windows OS, this file located in

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\res\values
```

After modified, save the file and restart android studio.